Laptop freezing, does the following section of the syslog show the culprit?
Apologies for the nondescript title, I'm a total beginner in these issues.
For several weeks now, my laptop (running Ubuntu 22.04) has been freezing regularly with the fan running at high speed, which I assume means that the CPU is working at high loads.  I've now taken a look at several /var/log/syslog (one example here) and a common theme is that the "Tasks state" table (line 1873 onwards) always lists an entry slack that has an abnormal total_vm:
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204087] Tasks state (memory values in pages):
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204088] [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
[... leaving out lots of lines for the sake of brevity ...]
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204095] [    770]     0   770    49386      564   401408      355          -250 systemd-journal
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204101] [    849]     0   849     6811      222    81920      520         -1000 systemd-udevd
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204107] [   1300]   108  1300     3709      162    73728      177          -900 systemd-oomd
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204112] [   1301]   101  1301     6524      327   102400      977             0 systemd-resolve
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204116] [   1302]   103  1302    22347      160    77824      178             0 systemd-timesyn
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204494] [   3580]  1000  3580 296853692    10587  1617920     4228             0 slack
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204505] [   3610]  1000  3610  8477519      148   589824     1776             0 skypeforlinux
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204509] [   3611]  1000  3611  8477516       14   606208     1875             0 skypeforlinux
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204512] [   3614]  1000  3614  8477516       13   450560     1882             0 skypeforlinux
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204533] [   3734]  1000  3734  8499511      199   708608     2093             0 slack
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204537] [   3736]  1000  3736  8499511      598   700416     1659             0 slack
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204553] [   3894]  1000  3894  8495000      861   712704     1684             0 skypeforlinux
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204556] [   3908]  1000  3908 10779379    32031  1867776     4500             0 skypeforlinux
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204559] [   3973]  1000  3973  8520125     1073   860160     2019             0 slack
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204562] [   3997]  1000  3997   420549     1167   249856      631             0 snap
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204566] [   4252]  1000  4252  8561739      257   716800     1841             0 skypeforlinux
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204574] [   4538]  1000  4538  8585844      319   856064     2073             0 slack
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204597] [   6077]  1000  6077  1314366   109736  5701632    20878             0 firefox
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204643] [ 107212]  1000 107212   383559   101022  1429504     5975             0 emacs-gtk
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204649] [ 145611]  1000 145611   450272    84326  2314240    97921             0 julia
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204679] [ 199883]  1000 199883   654254   429684  4337664     7395             0 julia
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204682] [ 200036]  1000 200036   323670   101561  1683456     4982             0 julia
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204685] [ 200063]  1000 200063   342541   108994  1785856     9742             0 julia
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204689] [ 204378]  1000 204378   471997   164703  2215936     4875             0 julia
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204693] [ 204677]  1000 204677   888815   336601  5427200      637             0 julia
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204786] [ 251672]  1000 251672  8485747     1952   634880        0             0 skypeforlinux
Jun  4 07:23:14 thinkpad kernel: [157532.204790] [ 251694]  1000 251694  8477555      206   532480     1707           200 skypeforlinux

Is it therefore safe to assume slack to be the most likely culprit of my system freezes?

It should be easy enough to test this assumption, if the freezes are frequent enough.

My laptop was also going slow/freezing and becoming unresponsive - I believe the problem was swap (even though it was on an SSD).   I reduced vm.swappiness to 10, and reduced the size of my swap file and the problem went away.  The fact that the first 2 lines of your screenshot talk about memory values in pages and oom_score_adj (ie out-of-memory score adjust) lead me to wonder if you are having a memory issue.

@harrymc True, I'll try running my laptop without slack over the weekend (I need to too much for work to test during the week).

@davidgo With memory do you mean RAM?  I'll keep that in mind if everything else fails and the issue persists.

Yes.I mean RAM (but also its interaction with swap/virtual ram - indeed its the process of swapping RAM to/from disk that is the issue - otherwise apps would just die rather then freeze the system.)
